# How to increment by 1 when copying value to next row in excel without using mouse?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to increment by 1 when copying value to next row in excel without using mouse ?

For example

```
GST-17/18/SO-001310
```

when I copy the above value and paste it in next row, I want it to be increment by 1 i.e how the formula can be used ?

```
GST-17/18/SO-001311
```

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "GST-17/18/SO-001310" is in A1, you can use:

```
=LEFT(A1,13)&TEXT(RIGHT(A1,6)+1,"000000")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select cell, then put mouse to down/right part of cell (until cross shows). click right mouse button and drag cross down. after releasing right mouse button, choose fill series from formatting options.

Comment: don't want to use mouse, just copy paste and it should increment the value by 1

Answer (score 0):

Enter 3-4 entries manually then select all the entered entries in that row,now drag the bottom end of the selected box downwards.

Comment: don't want to use mouse, just copy paste and it should increment the value by 1

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the area starting with the populated cell down to the place that you want to fill to.

`Alt-H` to home menu, `fi` to select 'fill', `s` to select 'Series' and tab to `type` and select `autofill` using the arrow keys.

This is based on Excel 2016.